# Prove that for all small $\epsilon>0$ there is only one function $\phi$ such that $F(t,\phi(t),\phi'(t))=0$ for every $(t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon)$ .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F: \mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a class $C^1$ function in an open $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $(t_0,x_0,y_0)$ a point of $\mathcal{U}$ such that $F(t_0,x_0,y_0)=0$ and $\partial_y F(t_0,x_0,y_0) \neq 0$. Prove that for every  small $\epsilon>0$  there is only one function $$\phi: (t_0- \epsilon , t_0 + \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$$ such that $$F(t, \phi(t), \phi'(t))=0$$ for every $(t_0- \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon)$ and $\phi(t_0)=x_0 $ and $\phi'(t_0)=y_0$.

I thought about using the implicit function theorem, to find a $g(t, x)$ and then consider $x'= g (t, x)$ and hence show that this equation has a unique solution, finally, show that this solution is a $\phi$ of the statement.

But I can't seem to develop the argument, could you help?

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of the equation,
$$
F_t+F_xx'+F_yx''=0
$$
to get the explicit second order IVP problem
$$
x''=-\frac{F_t(t,x,x')+F_x(t,x,x')x'}{F_y(t,x,x')},
~~ x(t_0)=x_0,~x'(t_0)=y_0.
$$
By assumption, this is continuous around the initial point, so the Peano theorem gives you a local solution, possibly non-unique.